# Имеет ли значение порядок "case-ов" в структуре "switch case"?

Tags: java, c++, c, switch

Я работаю с болшим количеством данных и они проходят через множество switch case операторов.

Есть ли разница в том как расределять case-ы внутри структуры? Будет ли более продуктивным поднять более часто встречаюшиеся случаи на первые строчки? Т.е. разбиваеться ли эта структура внутри на "if else" компоненты?

Работаю на java, но предполагаю что одинаковый подзод будет и в Сишеках.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/174065/ годная статья на хабре по теме

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких языков как Си, C++, C# - производительность весьма слабо зависит от количества блоков case и вовсе не зависит от их порядка (все равно компилятор их переупорядочит как ему нужно).

Для языка Java - производительность еще как зависит от порядка блоков, а иногда еще и результат может меняться (если вы используете класс с некорректной реализацией equals). Потому что компилятор Java преобразует оператор switch во что-то вроде серии "if - else if - else if - else"

Comment: _Java преобразует оператор switch во что-то вроде серии "if - else if - else if - else"_ - это в любой версии?

Comment: @Grundy да. Иначе просто невозможно реализовать: там же любой тип данных принимается.

Comment: gcc  по сути моделирует двоичный поиск, сравнивая с медианой из отсортированных case значений (возможно, если задать большой диапазон подряд, будет использовать таблицу переходов, но я не проверял)

Comment: эм. в java аргументом `switch` может быть выражение, результатом которого является `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int` (или подходящий упакованный примитив), строка или перечисление ([`jls-14.11`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)). Использовать класс с некорректным `equals` не получится. Для строк используется переход по `hashCode` и потом проверка на `equals`, поэтому для одинаковых хэшей порядок может быть важен, но я не нашел в спецификациях, где этот порядок оговаривается, и может ли компилятор его менять

Comment: @zRrr хм, тогда пространство для оптимизации все же есть. Но очень немного, и уже на уровне JVM, а не компилятора.

Answer (score 2):

В С и С++ невозможно заранее предсказать, каким образом будет реализован переход к конкретной метке `case` в `switch` - лесенкой ли `if-else`, прямым ли переходом через таблицу переходов, хитрым ли вычислением целевого адреса на основе параметра `switch` или еще как. Это зависит от массы факторов, включая такие очевидные, как количество меток `case`, плотность заполнения диапазона ваших меток `case` и т.п. Компиляторы, в зависимости от обстоятельств, будут использовать вариант по своему усмотрению.

Так как тело `switch` в языках C и С++ является одним непрерывным statement, компилятор в общем случае не имеет возможности как-либо переупорядочивать участки кода, выступающие в роли "реализаций" разных веток `case`. Это, разумеется, никак не мешает ему произвольно переупорядочивать код, отвественный за выбор точки входа в тело `switch`. Поэтому только в том случае, когда вы имеете основания полагать, что компилятор будет проверять условия вхождения в ветки линейно, по порядку, имеет смысл указывать более часто встречающиеся ветки первыми.

Answer (score -3):

Нет,компилятор для таких целей использует внутреннюю хэш-таблицу(очень рекомендую ознакомиться с такими терминами как Hash-table и [Branch_table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table) .Производительность зависит не от порядка,а от количества case-выражений.

Comment: Хэши тут вообще никаким боком. А создание таблицы переходов случается далеко не всегда.